# Variables externas en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo una funcion JS dentro de un HTML en un proyecto ASP.Net(especificamente un web form). Luego tengo otro proyecto con Keys y values.
Lo que quiero lograr es importar una de esas key dentro de mi script.

Intente haciendo esto pero no funciona:

```
 var prueba =  <%=Resources.Resources.Action_NameTooLong%>
            msgError("#msgErrorAgente", 6000, prueba);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue:

```
 var prueba =  "<%=Resources.Resources.Action_NameTooLong%>";
        msgError("#msgErrorAgente", 6000, prueba);
```

Debía agregar "" para que lo tomara como string.